# menorrhagia in early hyperthyroidism

Tags: endocrinology, hyperthyroid, menstrual-cycle

What is the pathophysiology of menustral irregularities in hyperthyroidism? Especially early menorrhagia seen in early hyperthyroidism?

Comment: Please answer someone..